# Ubuntu Network on startup

Tags: 12.04, networking

Network on my Ubuntu 12.04 is not getting initialized at startup. How can I force Ubuntu to initialize network upon start-up?
I am new to Ubuntu and have very limited understanding of files like `/etc/init.d` and `/etc/bashrc` files etc.
Right now, I am manually running this command every time from the terminal, after start up

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

I am sure there are much more sophisticated solutions to this problem. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For now you can put this command in `/etc/rc.local`.

```
service network-manager restart
```

In this way, every time you reboot/start PC NM will be started.

Answer (score 0):

A little strange that restarting Network Manager gets your networking back up after booting, but let's see if we can work around having to do that restart of it.

First, let's look at your `/etc/network/interfaces` file. You can open this through terminal with `gedit /etc/network/interfaces`. It should read something like

```
#The loopback network interace
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Where `eth0` would be a wired connection or `wlan` would be a wireless connection. Use whichever interface is desired for your computer.

Next, look at your `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file. It should read something like:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=00:30:48:70:D0:C3,

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

You will want the element of the `no-auto-default=` line to use the MAC hardware address of the `eth0` or `wlan` interface, which you can get from running `ifconfig` in Terminal. You'll see a line that contains `HWaddr 00:30:48:70:D0:C3` - the six-pair string is the MAC address to enter in that line.

Restart your system, and if all goes well, Network Manager will start, connect your interfaces and you'll be ready to go.